# Alternative to Razor and WebForms view engine that works well with jQuery & KnockoutJs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, nvelocity

I am stuck to using .NET 3.5, therefore using MVC3 is out of the question. After trying MVC2, I have to say that i prefer Monorail 2.0 over it, and especially the nVelocity view engine it uses. But at the same time, I've read about possible conflicts between nVelocity and the jQuery/KnockoutJs keyword '$', and I'm curious if ServiceStack's Razor view engine works on 3.5. I haven't found anything in their docs that specifies this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) implemention. They have a Razor engine and Markdown view engine which we are using. It works perfectly on Windows & Lunix (under Mono) and currently they have over 100 contributors to the project also. We've started using it recently for both services and UI's and have ditched WCF and MVC in favour of the service stack implementions. Sorry I should say it runs on 3.5

Comment: "Sorry I should say it runs on 3.5". Yay~!

Comment: Oops, sorry about that, I could have sworn I had read it was supported in 3.5, in fact I thought it 2.0 and above. My bad :(

Comment: Well, the ServiceStack core library supports 3.5, the RazorMarkdown ViewEngine doesn't.